# Facebook OpenGraph API calls does not work at all times

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We are not able to connect to Facebook OpenGraph API now and then. 
Our .NET client returns the below error:

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 66.220.146.100:443 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)

Please note that this is not specific to any particular API call.

Even pinging graph.facebook.com times out randomly.

Below is some trace route info:

```
1 <1 ms <1 ms <1 ms ip-97-74-87-252.ip.secureserver.net [97.74.87.252]
2 <1 ms <1 ms <1 ms ip-208-109-113-173.ip.secureserver.net [208.109.113.173]
3 1 ms <1 ms <1 ms ip-97-74-252-21.ip.secureserver.net [97.74.252.21]
4 1 ms <1 ms <1 ms ip-97-74-252-21.ip.secureserver.net [97.74.252.21]
5 9 ms 1 ms 1 ms 206-15-85-9.static.twtelecom.net [206.15.85.9]
6 13 ms 13 ms 44 ms lax2-pr2-xe-1-3-0-0.us.twtelecom.net [66.192.241.218]
7 26 ms 28 ms 27 ms cr1.la2ca.ip.att.net [12.122.104.14]
8 26 ms 27 ms 27 ms cr82.sj2ca.ip.att.net [12.122.1.146]
9 23 ms 23 ms 23 ms 12.122.128.201
10 22 ms 22 ms 22 ms 12.249.231.26
11 22 ms 22 ms 22 ms ae1.bb02.sjc1.tfbnw.net [204.15.21.164]
12 23 ms 23 ms 23 ms ae5.dr02.snc4.tfbnw.net [204.15.21.169]
13 24 ms 23 ms 23 ms eth-17-2.csw02b.snc4.tfbnw.net [74.119.76.105]
14 * * * Request timed out.
15 * * * Request timed out.
16 * * * Request timed out.
17 * * * Request timed out.
18 * * * Request timed out.
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Try pinging graph.facebook.com.
- Ping request will get timed out for certain IPs.

Comment: Related bug reporT: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/358274774239901?browse=search_4fe888930ca6b6d97826736